# JUnit formatted test output

Tags: polymer, web-component-tester

Jenkins doesn't notice my test cases being ran in Polymer and I am not so sure how to generate the correct JUnit file. With the [web-component-tester](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester) how do I generate JUnit formatted test output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This package](https://github.com/garcus/wct-xunit-reporter) ended up doing the trick for me.

#### Process

```
$ npm install wct-xunit-reporter
$ wct --plugin xunit-reporter
```

or add config to **wct.conf.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    local: {
      browsers: ['chrome']
    },
    sauce: false,
    'xunit-reporter': {
      'output': 'testfile.xml'
    }
  }
};
```

Run web-component-tester

`$ wct`