# How to display the XUnit test output on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, web-component-tester, wct

According to [JUnit formatted test output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271876/junit-formatted-test-output) I created an XUnit report xml with https://github.com/garcus/wct-xunit-reporter.

What does not work is that Jenkins displays the Test-Results. I tried:

- different XUnit Test Results (Publish xUnit test result report: [xUnit] [ERROR] - The converted file for the result file '..../testfile.xml' (during conversion process for the metric 'NUnit') is not valid.)
- the JUnit Test Results

Is there another XUnit xsl needed, or what else do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct test result type:

xUnit.Net-v2

That must be choosen in the dropdown of 'Publish xUnit test result report'